# Remove file without asking

Tags: linux, shell

How can I remove a file without asking the user if he agrees to delete the file? I am writing shell script and use rm function, but it asks "remove regular file?" and I really don't need this.

Comment: `rm -f`, `yes | rm` and so on, but this belongs to SU.

Comment: `rm` doesn't show a "remove regular file?" prompt by default.  You must have it aliased to `rm -i`, or defined as a function.  I'm surprised that the alias is visible inside your script.  Are you executing the script (`./foo.sh`) or sourcing it (`. foo.sh` or `source foo.sh`)?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You might have `rm` aliased to `rm -i` so try this:

```
/bin/rm -f file.log
```

To see your aliases you can run `alias`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `command rm ...` or `\rm ...` to skip the alias/function

Comment: It's been argued that having `rm` aliased to `rm -i` is a bad idea.  The `rm` command, by default, silently removes the named file.  By aliasing it to `rm -i`, you can get into the habit of not checking carefully before pressing Enter, depending on the interactive prompt to save you.  Then you type `rm some-important-file` in an environment without the alias.

Comment: @Keith That is very true, i only personally alias rm to rm -v

Comment: If "rm" is a function (instead of an alias), this answer should work. And the bash `unset` command might be interesting

Comment: This does not work for removing more than 100 files...

Answer (score 85):

The force flag removes all prompts;

`rm -f {file}`

Comment: This is what I am looking for, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 44):

May the force be with you - `rm -f`

Comment: I upvoted both the comment AND the answer just because someone actually found a sense of humor on SO...

Answer (score 9):

the `yes` program repeatedly replies yes to any prompts. so you can pipe it into the interactive `rm` program to get the desired effect too.

```
yes | rm <filename>
```

conversely, if you want to not do something interactive, you can do

```
yes n | <something interactive>
```

and that will repeat 'n' on the input stream (effectively answering no to questions)

Comment: The `yes n` option is not working for me. While I use `yes n | rm file.txt`, it actually removes the file even though the file is right protected.

Answer (score 7):

```
\rm file
```

Backslash `\` bypasses aliases.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the required permissions to delete the file and you don't want to be prompted, do the following (-f = force):

```
rm -f file
```

If you don't have permissions to the file, you will need to use:

```
sudo rm -f file
```

Comment: The "remove regular file?" prompt implies that it's not a permissions problem.

Answer (score 5):

Within a shell script, you would want to use `rm -f <filename>` but you also have the option of getting rid of the implicit `-i` option for your environment by entering `unalias rm` in your shell (or profile).

Comment: `unalias rm` doesn't work in CentOS? Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Apart of using `-f` parameter, alternatively you can use `find` command instead, e.g.

```
find -name file.log -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

My favourite way to do this is simply use `command` command in bash, just the same way you use `sudo`. This will run your command without aliases, just like running it by `/bin/rm` (probably `rm` is aliased as `rm -i`).

Example:

```
command rm -f /tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working at a system, where the bash shell recieved the definition of the rm command as a function in one of the global configuration files:

```
 rm  () { /bin/rm -i ${1+"$@"}; }
```

Hence, none of the above answers regarding aliases did work. To counter the annoying behaviour I unset the rm function in my .bashrc file

```
 unset -f rm
```

I had a similar problem then the opener. However I did not found any answer that mentioned the possibility that `rm` is hidden by a shell function. So I added the answer here in the hope it would be of help for somebody facing the same type of problem.

Typing `/bin/rm` or `rm -f` all the time is inconvenient, and may have bad consequences (in the case of `rm -f`).

Comment: That may have solved your problem but it does not answer the question.

Comment: Wouldn't the selected answer - calling `/bin/rm` work? If I have a function in bash, and an executable file with the same name in the current directory, just adding `./` in front of the name will call the file - not the function. PS - I added a comment to the selected answer about a function & `unset`

Comment: Yes, `/bin/rm` works. Doing the `unset` removes the need for typing the full path.

Answer (score 0):

If your `rm` is aliased to `rm -i`, then use `unalias rm`;

Do not use `rm -f` directly unless you really want to remove a lot of write-protected files.  There must be a very good reason to use `-f`.

However, if you have a lot of write-protected files, you might prefer to `rsync -r --delete empty/ removed_dir/` for a faster speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -Rf <folder-to-be-deleted>
```

> -R: Recursive f: force, no prompt

Comment: nooo. just no. if recursive was not already on the command... this can tank the whole system in some cases like a newbie trying to remove all hidden files with 
`rm */.*` 
(one example)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a folder containing everything you want to delete, this can help
cd directory
find . -print |xargs  rm -r

Comment: This seems more complex than some of the other answers. Why should someone use this instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I noticed is that if I remove multiple files/dirs through in one go like the following then the rm command asks for confirmation.

```
sudo rm -rf dir1 dir2
```

If I remove them them one by one then it doesn't ask for confirmation.

```
sudo rm -rf dir1 
sudo rm -rf dir2
```